# Why material ui constantly updating their implementation, syntax?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I m new to material ui, i followed one of the youtube tutorial video which is uploaded few months back, i followed the video step up step, but still showing error,(i installed latest version, in tutorial its different version) because of material ui changes their way of implementation in every update, why its so, they should be consistent right? is there any good way to learn quickly material ui?

example code

```
import { AppBar, InputBase, Toolbar, Typography } from '@mui/material'
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles'
import ManageSearchIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ManageSearch';

import React from 'react'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme)=> ({
    toolbar:{
        display:"flex",
        justifyContent:"space-between"
    },
    logoLg:{
        display: "none",
        [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]:{
            display:"block"
        }
    },
    logoSm:{
        display: "block",
        [theme.breakpoints.up('lg')]:{
            display:"none"
        }
    },
    search:{

    }
}));
function NavBar() {
    const classes = useStyles()
  return (
    <AppBar>
        <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
            <Typography variant='h6' className={classes.logoLg}> Ajmal
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant='h6' className={classes.logoSm}> AN
            </Typography>
            <div className={classes.search}>
                <ManageSearchIcon />
                <InputBase placeholder='Search ./-' /> 
            </div>
        </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  )
}

export default NavBar

import { AppBar, InputBase, Toolbar, Typography } from '@mui/material'
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles'
import ManageSearchIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ManageSearch';

import React from 'react'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme)=> ({
    toolbar:{
        display:"flex",
        justifyContent:"space-between"
    },
    logoLg:{
        display: "none",
        [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]:{
            display:"block"
        }
    },
    logoSm:{
        display: "block",
        [theme.breakpoints.up('lg')]:{
            display:"none"
        }
    },
    search:{

    }
}));
function NavBar() {
    const classes = useStyles()
  return (
    <AppBar>
        <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
            <Typography variant='h6' className={classes.logoLg}> Ajmal
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant='h6' className={classes.logoSm}> AN
            </Typography>
            <div className={classes.search}>
                <ManageSearchIcon />
                <InputBase placeholder='Search ./-' /> 
            </div>
        </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  )
}

export default NavBar
```

[image]Good way of learning material ui

Comment: No, the idea behind *major* version updates is that backwards compatibility is not ensured. This could be small changes, or major ones. I believe in the latest MUI major version there have been _significant_ changes to the library. You can either update all your code or just install a previous version

Comment: yeah no backward compatibility